# Bash 3.2's behavior of logical or || operator in arithmetic expressions

Tags: bash

I experimented on the latest mac OS with a shell scrip "a.sh" with the following content (exact copy).

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $BASH_VERSION
a=0
(( a < 100 || 1 / a < 2 )) && echo ok
```

I got:

```
3.2.57(1)-release
./a.sh: line 4: ((: a < 100 || 1 / a < 2 : division by 0 (error token is "< 2 ")
```

Since `a < 100` is already true, I thought `1 / a < 2` wouldn't be evaluated.

Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on bash 5, which version do you have?

Comment: Nothing at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html indicates that `||` in an arithmetic expression does short-cutting; maybe it simply doesn't? (Surprising, I admit.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two circumstances you got this error:

1. Bash 3.2.57 evaluates both sides of a logical `or` within an arithmetic expression.
2. or because you used a single `|` bit-wise ∨, rather than a double `||` logical ∨ boolean expression operator:

```sh
LC_ALL=C bash -c 'a=0; (( a < 100 | 1 / a < 2 )) && echo ok'
```

> `bash: ((: a < 100 | 1 / a < 2 : division by 0 (error token is "a < 2 ")`

```sh
LC_ALL=C bash -c 'a=0; (( a < 100 || 1 / a < 2 )) && echo ok'
```

> `ok`

Reason:
`|` is the bit-wise `or` operator.

When used as:

`a < 100 | 1 / a < 2`,

the bit-wise `or` applies as:

`100 | 1`,

witch in binary is equivalent to `01100100 ∨ 00000001` → `01100101` binary or `101` base-10.

Finally:

`a < 100 | 1 / a < 2` turns-out to be:

`a < 101 / a < 2`.

When `a=0`:

`0 < 101 / 0 < 2`

Comment: Thanks for helping. I edited the question to make the shell version clear. This is probably a version compatibility issue since it works for you. Appreciate the extra info on "||" and "|".

Comment: @JoeSmith I reproduced this with Bash 3.2.57, so it is clearly a specific behavior of this version. Anyway I realized that `1 / a < 2` will be always true in Bash arithmetic context since it only deals with integers → 1/ℕ is always < 1.